# cropping unwanted map part in cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm using cartopy to draw global histograms with matplotlib.
There is a part in the map which I don't want to show, but it is in the longitude and the latitude that I need (so setting an extent can't help here).

I know there is a way to create a mask for an area, but I'm having a little trouble with it.
The area that I want to crop isn't a country or anything specific, just a coastline...
Can I create a mask using the Long and the Lat values only?
The goal is to show only the Mediterranean sea, and not anything else, so I don't want to see the northern coasts of France and Spain that aren't a part of the Mediterranean coastline.
Thank you guys,
Karin.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

I used `ax.add_patch(rectangle)` to cover that part in the plot.